# Problem with generate pdf and content version

Tags: lightning-web-components

i need Generate PDF using LWC from Quick Action.

pdfTemplate.page

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Account">

<h1>Account Details</h1>

Dear {!account.Name}, <br/><br/>
Below are the Account details: <br/>
Type: {!account.Type} <br/>
Account Number: {!account.AccountNumber} </apex:page>
```

CreatePdfController

```
public with sharing class CreatePdfController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Id generatePdf(String idAccount){
    Blob strPdfBody = null;
    Attachment objAttach = new Attachment();
    try {
        Account objAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :idAccount LIMIT 1];
        PageReference objPagePdf = Page.PdfTemplate;
        objPagePdf.getParameters().put('Id', idAccount);
        strPdfBody =  objPagePdf.getContent();

        ContentVersion objVersion = new ContentVersion();
        objVersion.ContentLocation = 'S';
        objVersion.PathOnClient = 'Test ' +objAccount.Name +'.pdf';
        objVersion.Title = 'Test ' +objAccount.Name;
        objVersion.VersionData = strPdfBody;
        insert objVersion;

        Id objDocId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:objVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId;
        ContentDocumentLink objDocumentLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
        objDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = objAccount.Id;
        objDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = objDocId;
        objDocumentLink.shareType = 'V';
        insert objDocumentLink;
        return objDocumentLink.Id;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
} }
```

createPdf.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

<apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>

<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
        <actionType>Action</actionType>
    </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
```

headlessQuickAction.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class HeadlessQuickAction extends LightningElement {

@api invoke() {
    const successToast = new ShowToastEvent({
        title : "Headless Quick Action!",
        message : "Headless Quick Action executed successfully.",
        variant : 'success'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(successToast);
} }
```

When I add

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
        <actionType>Action</actionType>
    </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
```

I don't see this component in the Lighting builder.

When i add

```
 <targets>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
```

I can see the component, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please stop mis-using tags. Tags are meant to describe what a question contains or is about. The "Community" tag is for a specific feature, Community sites (also called Experience Cloud sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to see it in the Lighting builder ?

If you want to Generate PDF using LWC from Quick Action then you **need to create Appropriate Quick Action** :

[image]

Also you **did not import your Apex method in your LWC** !!
See how to do it and then use **"connectedCallback()"** to call your Apex method :

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import generatePdf from '@salesforce/apex/CreatePdfController.generatePdf';
 
export default class HeadlessQuickAction extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;

  connectedCallback() {
    generatePdf({idAccount : '$recordId'}).then( result => {
        const successToast = new ShowToastEvent({
            title : "Headless Quick Action!",
            message : "Headless Quick Action executed successfully.",
            variant : 'success'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(successToast);
    }).catch( error => {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error',
            message: error,
            variant: 'error'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main issue is described in the previous answer.
In addition, the apex pages with standard controllers use "id" parameter. So, it would be better to change the Apex code line 
`objPagePdf.getParameters().put('Id', idAccount);`
to
`objPagePdf.getParameters().put('id', idAccount);`

Hope it hepls